# Can I use API Google Font in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I use iTextSharp for Create PDF in my project
and i have problem about Font...

This is my code...

```
 //Path to our font
 string arialuniTffFont = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF");
 //Register the font with iTextSharp
 iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(arialuniTffFont);

 fontTitleReport = BaseFont.CreateFont(arialuniTffFont, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

it's work in my local Project But in Cloud it's not work
Error Occur about Cloud Cannot see path of my Font(c:\Window\Font\...)

How to fix its...Help Me Pleae T^T

ps. I want to use this font(Arial Unicode MS) Because in my report i want to create many Language.(Ex: English, Japanese, Thai, etc.)

Comment: You can use "FontSelector" class..

Answer (score 1):

**Reason for failure :**
it is working in your local PC because you have installed/copied your Fonts into `C:\Windows\Fonts` location. but you have not installed those fonts in your remote PC.

**Solution:**
you need to install/copy your fonts into `C:\Windows\Fonts` location of your cloud.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you don't have a file system (for instance on Google App Engine), you need to use a different `createFont()` method, more specifically one of the methods that accepts a stream as parameter.

Instead of passing the location of the font file as a parameter, you need to pass the `byte[]` of the font program. See for instance: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseFont.html#createFont(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, byte[], byte[])

In your case, you're talking about a TTF file, so you need to pass the bytes of this file as parameter `ttfAfm` and the parameter `pfb` can be `null` (this parameter is only used for Type1 fonts where a font program consists of two files: an AFM file and a PFB file).